# Inversion mapping $w = f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ maps

Tags: complex-analysis

Inversion mapping $w = f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ maps the ray Arg $z$ = $\theta_0$ , $-\pi < \theta_0 < \pi$, onto the ray Arg $w$ = $-\theta_0$

so what I did was for $z = re^{i\theta_0}$ on the ray Arg $z$ = $\theta_0$ and the same thing for $w = \frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta_0}$ for Arg $w = e^{-i\theta_0}$

I am stuck and have no idea what do next to show it is onto.

Comment: You cant get the point $(0,-\theta_0)$ on the ray $-\theta_0$! so it is not onto

Comment: the book has its onto.

Comment: then what point will be mapped onto $(0,-\theta)$ could it be $(0,\theta)$? this only possible if you consider the point $(\infty , \theta_0)$ in your domain then this will be mapped into $(0,-\theta_0)$ and $(0,\theta_0)$ will be mapped into $(\infty,-\theta_0)$. Consider $(\infty,\theta_0)  = (-\infty,\theta_0)$

Comment: It's onto if you either exclude $0$ from all rays or include $\infty$ in all rays. Which you should when dealing with an inversion.

Comment: so, the book has the following," taking 0 < r < $\infty$ shows that this mapping goes onto ray Arg w" 

I am lost how this will be mapping onto from 0 to infinity.

Comment: So it exclude the 0.